# Table rendering on Windows 10 adding white space

Tags: html, windows, windows-10, css-tables

I am using Photoshop slices -- yes, yes, it's 2018, and we no longer need slices and table layouts...except when we do. My image is an extremely large piece of custom art, and I have to identify 50-odd people within it.

So I made slices of all the people I needed to identify in the image and created Photoshop's html table and image layout. Everything works fine on all browsers and platforms EXCEPT Chrome on Windows 10! Does anyone have any insight as to what is going on please?

Please do not mark this question down. If I'm doing something wrong, or you have a suggestion, please let me know.

```
<table id="Table_01" width="2187" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">

* {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}
#Table_01 {
    width: 2187px;
    height: 3649px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
table td { 
    font-size:0px !important;
    line-height: 0px !important; 
}
img { 
    display:block !important; 
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
}
```

I am temporarily posting my site [here](https://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/test-nl/index1.php).

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D: If need be, I'll link to the published website once it's finished.

Comment: can you please add which browser/OS is creating that problem ?

Comment: @Dirk: It only happens on Windows 10.

Comment: @Rob: How would you accomplish it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh. I had to abandon this whole approach. Nothing seemed to help Windows 10 render a complex table without white space between the images. I ended up making a big image map using Adobe Fireworks. Then, of course, I had to abandon Bootstrap Tooltips because they don't work with image maps. I used jqueryui Tooltips instead.

html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>    

<img name="fireworks" src="img/fireworks.jpg" width="2186" height="3648" border="0" id="fireworks" usemap="#m_fireworks" alt="" />
    <map name="m_fireworks" id="m_fireworks">
    <area shape="rect" coords="930,288,1244,544" title="<span class='tt-header'>Person 1</span><br/><span class='tt-body'>my title</span>" alt="dippy" id="" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="1507,2131,1566,2249" title="<span class='tt-header'>Person 2</span><br/><span class='tt-body'>my title</span>" alt="nellie" id="" />
    ...
    </map>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you have it figured out on larger screen sizer (such as your computer monitor) but when it comes to smaller screen sizes, everything goes wrong. 
What you're going to need to do is use Google's responsive device toolbar feature to find out what screen size your image starts to suffer at and then create a media query to target the screen sizes that aren't right.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp - This link will give you a quick intro to media queries (they're pretty simple to pick up). 
At the moment, your code is just assuming that all screen sizes will act the same, which they don't because things are never that easy ;-)

Feel free to ask any follow up questions if you get stuck!

Comment: It seems it's a Windows 10 problem, not a media query issue.